# Combining two data sets based on programme name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi I am trying to work out the best way to achieve something.  I am essentially making two database calls

```
const [emails] = await dbConnection.execute('SELECT name, programme, timestamp FROM emails');
const [emailsCancelled] = await dbConnection.execute('SELECT data FROM emails where name = "email.cancelled"');
```

The reason I am making two calls is that I am processing over hundred thousand rows, and the data field contains quite a bit of JSON data, so don't want to retrieve that for all the rows.

So with the emails, I get data back in the following format

```
[
    {
    name: 'email.sent',
    programme: 'Email One',
    timestamp: 2022-03-24T18:06:02.000Z
    },
    {
    name: 'email.sent',
    programme: 'Email Two',
    timestamp: 2022-03-24T18:06:02.000Z
    },
    {
    name: 'email.sent',
    programme: 'Email One',
    timestamp: 2022-03-24T18:06:02.000Z
    },
    ...
]
```

So what I needed to do is group by programme, to identify how many were sent and the total count.  I do obtain some other details but reduced for this post.  To do this I do

```
const emailsReduced = await emails.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const name = o.name?.replace('email.', '');
  if (!acc[o.programme]) {
    acc[o.programme] = {
      count: 0,
      sent: 0,
    };
  }
  acc[o.programme].count = (acc[o.programme].count || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.programme][name] = (acc[o.programme][name]) + 1;

  return acc;
}, {});
```

And that will return something like this

```
'Email One': {
    count: 2,
    sent: 2,
},
'Email Two': {
    count: 1,
    sent: 1,
},
```

Now emailsCancelled returns JSON data.  So what I can do is loop it and show an example out the part I need

```
Object.entries(emailsCancelled).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(value.data);
  if (data?.payload?.body?.toUpperCase() === 'STOP') {
    console.log(data?.payload?.correlation?.metadata);
  }
});
```

And that will produce rows like this

```
[
    { customerId: '12345', programName: 'Email One' },
    { customerId: '2321', programName: 'Email Two' },
    { customerId: '33321', programName: 'Email Two' }
]
```

Now what I need to do is get that into the original array as a count.  So you can see that there was 1 cancelled for Email One, and 2 for Two.  So I need to add this in like so, matching it based on the programme name.

```
'Email One': {
    count: 2,
    sent: 2,
    cancelled: 1,
},
'Email Two': {
    count: 1,
    sent: 1,
    cancelled: 2,
},
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Thanks

**Actual format**

```
{
   "name":"email.cancelled",
   "payload":{
      "body":"STOP",
      "correlation":{
         "metadata":{
            "customerId":"232131232113",
            "programName":"Email One"
         }
      },
      "id":"123454323343232",
      "receivedOn":"2022-05-15T12:51:54.403Z"
   },
}
```

Comment: do a reduce on the cancelled list with `emailsReduced` as the accumulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `emailsCancelled`, you can reduce your array to a lookup [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) before your perform your `.reduce()` on on `emails`. The lookup will store the `programName` as the keys, and the count of that program as the values:

```js
const emails = [
    { customerId: '12345', programName: 'Email One' },
    { customerId: '2321', programName: 'Email Two' },
    { customerId: '33321', programName: 'Email Two' }
];

const lut = emails.reduce((map, {programName}) => 
  map.set(programName, (map.get(programName) || 0) + 1)
, new Map);

console.log(lut.get("Email One"));
console.log(lut.get("Email Two"));
```

You can build this Map directly from your `.forEach()` loop also, note that I'm using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) instead of `.entries()` as you're only intrested in the values and not the keys:

```js
const lut = new Map();
Object.values(emailsCancelled).forEach(value => {
  const data = JSON.parse(value.data);
  if (data?.payload?.body?.toUpperCase() === 'STOP') {
    const programName = data.payload.correlation?.metadata?.programName; // if `correcltation`, or `metadata` or `programName` don't exist, use optional chaining and an if-statement to check for `undefined` before updating the map.
    lut.set(programName, (map.get(programName) || 0) + 1)
  }
});
```

You can then use this lookup `lut` Map when you use `.reduce()` on emails to work out the `cancelled` value, defaulting `cancelled` to `0` if the programme can't be found in the Map:

```
const emailsReduced = await emails.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const name = o.name?.replace('email.', '');
  if (!acc[o.programme]) {
    acc[o.programme] = {
      count: 0,
      sent: 0,
      cancelled: lut.get(o.programme) || 0 // default to zero if program can't be found
    };
  }
  acc[o.programme].count = acc[o.programme].count + 1;
  acc[o.programme][name] = acc[o.programme][name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit to my post as I stripped back the actual format not thinking that it would make a difference.  So it will be an array of Objects in my format, where programName is embedded within it.  

That is why I initially had 

`if (data?.payload?.body?.toUpperCase() === 'STOP') {
    console.log(data?.payload?.correlation?.metadata);
  }`

To check if the body contained STOP, and only do the count based on this.  I tried using your suggestion, but getting undefined.  I assume because it is embedded?

Comment: @TTBox It depends on what you're calling `.reduce()` on to create the Map. In my example, I'm calling it on an array of objects that you've logged. In your code your would either need to put the objects you're logging into an array so that it matches the same format as `emails` above, or create the Map within your loop (see [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72247959/2)). I've also defaulted the value for `cancelled` by adding `|| 0` if the programme can't be found in the Map.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.  I think it should be lut.get instead of map.get though in the new example?

Comment: @TTBox Yeah, that's right :) should've been `lut.get()` and not `map.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data structures look like these, you can map and filter according to `emails` keys:

```js
const emails = [
    { 'Email One': {
    count: 2,
    sent: 2,
    }},
    {'Email Two': {
    count: 1,
    sent: 1,
    }}
]

const canceled = [
  { customerId: '12345', programName: 'Email One' },
  { customerId: '2321', programName: 'Email Two' },
  { customerId: '33321', programName: 'Email Two' }
]

const newmails = emails.map(mail => {
  let strmail = Object.keys(mail)
  let ncanceled = canceled.filter(item => {
    return item.programName == strmail
  }).length
  mail[strmail].canceled = ncanceled
  return mail
})

console.log(newmails)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
const emails = [{
    'Email One': {
      count: 2,
      sent: 2,
      cancelled: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    'Email Two': {
      count: 1,
      sent: 1,
      cancelled: 0,
    },
  },
];

const cancelled_emails = [{
    customerId: '12345',
    programName: 'Email One'
  },
  {
    customerId: '2321',
    programName: 'Email Two'
  },
  {
    customerId: '33321',
    programName: 'Email Two'
  },
];



for (let cancelled_email of cancelled_emails) {
  let prg_name = cancelled_email.programName;

  for (email of emails) {

    if (Object.keys(email)[0] === prg_name) {
      email[prg_name].cancelled += 1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(emails);
```